# Install iOS 17 Developer on iPhone 8 Plus to run Apple Watch 9

Tags: iphone, mobile-device-management, apple-watch.app

I bought the Apple Watch 9 not knowing that it cannot run on my iPhone 8 Plus. I am trying to make a save! I signed up for iOS 17 developer beta and got it installed, but it is not running. My software update window still shows iOS 16.7.2. I have watched the videos I can find, and I follow the steps, but I must be missing something. Does anyone have any experience or resources that could help me get the iOS 17 Developer software running? Or any other workarounds for the Apple Watch 9?

Comment: What version of Xcode and macOS are you running?

Comment: ios 16.7.2, Where do I find out about xcode? I may be out of my depth here, lol. The update screen shows the Betas but no icon to click on. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you just return the watch?  You have to have a compatible phone to pair it with, and you do not.